# $(E_n - E_m) \omega_{mn} = \sum_l (\omega_{ml}H_{ln}-H_{ml}\omega_{ln})$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue

It's an expression from Landau Lifshitz *Statistical physics*, where $\omega$ is density matrix. I have troubles with going from eigenvalues $E_n$ and $E_m$ to Hamiltonian matrix elements, besides putted in in different order regard \omega.
What I understand:
$$
 \hat{H} \phi |n\rangle = E_n \phi |n\rangle,\ 
H_{nm} = \langle n|\hat{H}|m\rangle $$ - is a matrix element but how the matrix of Hamiltonian is looking now I barely see.
I also know that Hamiltonian is hermitian operator, so $ \langle\hat{H}n|m\rangle = \langle n|\hat{H}m\rangle $, however I don't see clear way to derive the given expression.

Comment: What is $\phi$ here?

Comment: wave(eigen)function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the specifics of the context, but if this is all, then this seems like fairly simple algebra,
$$ \sum_{l}(\omega_{ml}H_{ln}-H_{ml}\omega_{ln}) = \sum_{l}\Big(\langle m|\omega|l\rangle \langle l|H|n\rangle- \langle m|H|l\rangle \langle l |\omega|n\rangle\Big) = \sum_{l}\Big(\langle m|\omega|l\rangle \langle l|n\rangle E_{n}- E_{m}\langle m|l\rangle \langle l |\omega|n\rangle\Big)$$
Using the completeness of the energy basis (which I assume holds since you have made no mention of it),
$$ \sum_{l}\Big(\langle m|\omega|l\rangle \langle l|n\rangle E_{n}- E_{m}\langle m|l\rangle \langle l |\omega|n\rangle\Big) = \langle m|\omega\Big(\sum_{l}|l\rangle \langle l|\Big)|n\rangle E_{n}- E_{m}\langle m|\Big(\sum_{l}|l\rangle \langle l|\Big) \omega|n\rangle = \omega_{mn}(E_{n} - E_{m})$$

Comment: so my question is regard the step going from $<l|H|n>$ to $<l|n>E_n$ and from $<m|H|l>$ to $E_m<m|l>$. How do you get it from inside the brackets and how is the index assigned? There's smth I miss about bra-ket notation but yet I cannot find a comprehensive answer.

Comment: The states you provide are energy eigenstates and the Hamiltonian (the "energy" operator) acts on them as $\hat{H} |n\rangle = E_{n} |n\rangle$. The index is used to label which state it is (typically, $|0\rangle$ is the ground state, $|1\rangle$ the first excited state) and $E_{n}$ refers to the energy of the $n^{th}$ state. Since the operator is Hermitian, it can act on the left as well as the right to give the appropriate energy value - if it was not Hermitian, acting on the left would result in something different.

Comment: In case you want a proper idea about the bra/ket notation, refer to the first chapter of Sakurai's textbook (Modern Quantum Mechanics, if I am not wrong).